# Find equation of the plane through the origin with basis <1,2,-1> and <2,3,4>.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find an equation of the plane through the origin with basis <1,2,-1> and <2,3,4>.

Could I get some advice on how to work this problem? I know how to find the basis given some plane, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Compute the cross product of the two vectors. This vector will be orthogonal to the plane and from there you get the equation.

Comment: Okay,so the cross product would be 11i-6j-k? So is this the actual equation I'm looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's the cross product. No, that's not an equation. Given a normal vector $ai+bj+ck$ to a plane $P$ through the origin, an equation for $P$ is given by $ax+by+cz=0$.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry this is not quicker for me to pick up. I appreciate your comments. So, what should I do now with the cross product? Is that the same thing as my "normal" vector? If so, would I just use 11x-6y-z? I think I'm getting confused on how to get from the cross product to the normal vector. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the vector you get when you compute the cross product is a normal vector to the plane. Since you got $11i-6j-k$ as normal vector, an equation for the plane is $11x-6y-z=0$. And don't worry, we are all learning. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative hint** $\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$

The vector form for the equation of the plane is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=s\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\-1\end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\\-4\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $s,t\in{\mathbb R}$.

Given an arbitrary point $P=[x,y,z]^T$ on the plane, there must be an $s$ and $t$ so that $P$ can be expressed using the above equation; i.e. $\vec{p}=s\:\vec{a}+t\:\vec{b}$ is a consistent linear system. What conditions must there be on $P$ for this to hold?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use determinates for quick way :
$$\begin{vmatrix}
x & y  & z &1 \\ 
 1&2  &-1  &1 \\ 
 2&3  & 4 & 1\\ 
0 &0  &0  &1 
\end{vmatrix} =0 $$